# Aligning equation with plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, align

I want to align an equation with its graph, this is what it currently looks like.

[image]

And this is what I want...

[image]

How could I change the first one to look like the second?

This

This is what my code looks like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,amssymb,amsthm}

\begin{document}

\[ f(t) =
    \begin{cases}
        e^{-\frac{1}{t}} & t > 0    \\
        0                & t \leq 0
    \end{cases}
\]

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  grid=both,
  xmin=-2.1,
  xmax=2.1,
  ymin=-2.1,
  ymax=2.1,
  axis lines=middle,
  xlabel = $x$,
  ylabel = $y$,
  axis line style={latex-latex},
  ]

\addplot[
  samples=100,
  domain=0.01:2,
  color=blue,
  thick,
  smooth,
  ]
  {(e)^(-1/x)};


\addplot[
  samples=2,
  domain=-2:0,
  color=blue,
  thick,
  smooth
  ]
  {0};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I tried using multicols* but it breaks everything, the graph sometimes doesn't show up or it moves to a blank page at the end of the chapter.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippet be compilabel, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert the graph in the display:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,amssymb,amsthm}

\begin{document}

\[ f(t) =
    \begin{cases}
        e^{-\frac{1}{t}} & t > 0    \\
        0                & t \leq 0
    \end{cases}
\qquad
\begin{gathered}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  grid=both,
  xmin=-2.1,
  xmax=2.1,
  ymin=-2.1,
  ymax=2.1,
  axis lines=middle,
  xlabel = $x$,
  ylabel = $y$,
  axis line style={latex-latex},
  ]
\addplot[
  samples=100,
  domain=0.01:2,
  color=blue,
  thick,
  smooth,
  ]
  {(e)^(-1/x)};
\addplot[
  samples=2,
  domain=-2:0,
  color=blue,
  thick,
  smooth
  ]
  {0};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{gathered}
\]

\end{document}
```

With `gathered` you get vertical centering.

[image]